# GRpc protobuf generic client runtime

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, grpc, .net-5, protobuf-net

i'm trying to create a dotnet core 5 app with multiple GRpc clients/servers generated from protobuf files.
One of the servers should act like a "master" to handle the life cycle of the whole app from one endpoint.

All clients implements a common interface

```
public interface IClient {
    public Task PingAsync()
}
```

And one of the service protobuf. All services protobuf have this `Ping` method.

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

package services;

service Service1{
  rpc Ping(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
  ...More specific methods...
}
```

I would like the master server to be able to communicate with all the services with clients as `IClient`. The only information that the Master has is the url/port of each other GRpc server.

Is there a way to create a sort of "base class" for clients which the launcher will be able to use. Something like

```
var client = new GenericClient(url, port);
await client.PingAsync();
```

so servers keep having only one proto file.

Servers already exist and would want to make not too much modifications if possible.
Especially, i would like to have only one proto file by server if possible.

Because servers already exists, they already using this `Ping` method to communicate between them so i would like to keep using it if possible.

Comment: Are all the clients gRPC-based? If so, why don't you declare that common client as a separate .proto file, and just register each server as implementing that common service?

Comment: Yes they all are, but all clients are also implementing more specific methods. So Client1Impl has, for exemple, another method in its proto named `rpc DoStuff1(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}` and another client named Client2Impl has other methods. As far as i know, in dotnet, GRpc client can inherit only one generated GRpc client.
Or i just didn't understand your recommandation ^^.

Comment: One solution i can think of is having a dedicated GRpc services for this on all the servers.
For exemple, Server1 will have its Server1Impl and CommonImpl Grpc services and Server2 will have Server2Impl and its own CommonImpl.
But i wanted to know if there a simpler method

Comment: What's unclear to me is why you particularly need to have the more-specific client in the same class as the generic ping client. So long as all the servers *implement* the ping client, isn't that enough? Fundamentally I can't really tell what you're trying to achieve - it feels like we've only got half the story. The fact that the clients are generated as partial classes *might* help, as you can easily say that `Client1` implements `IClient`. But as I don't understand what you're trying to do, I can't suggest that as an actual answer post.

Comment: Because i wanted to have only one proto file so servers are also in the class and i need to maintain only one instance for each servers for communication especially because servers already exists and already implement Ping but separatly in their own proto files.
And i wanted to limit servers modifications.
But if its the best solution i guess i can work with that

Comment: @JonSkeet i updated my post. Sorry i tried to keep it short, but i guess it was too short ^^.

Comment: With the way that services are identified in gRPC, I really think that just implementing two services (the specific one and the ping one) is going to be the simplest way to go. If the ping implementation is the same in each server, you could use a common class for that and just add that as well as the specific service when you configure the service. While it may mean making changes to each server once while you refactor, I think it'll be the neatest solution.

Comment: @JonSkeet just FYI: protobuf-net has some capabilities here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion with @JonSkeet, there is no "simple" solution the cover everything that i want to do.

The best workaround is to create a dedicated Ping GRpc service.

This service will then be added as GRpc service in each server. So the Master can instantiate a Ping client for each Server.

Answer (score 2):

I'll "see" your one proto file, and instead go for "zero proto files", via protobuf-net.Grpc:

Consider:

```cs
[SubService]
public interface IClient {
    Task PingAsync();
}

[Service]
public interface IFooClient : IClient {
  // other methods here
}

[Service]
public interface IBarClient : IClient {
  // other methods here
}
```

Now, at the client:

```cs
var foo = channel.CreateGrpcService<IBarClient>();
foo.Whatever(...);
//...
await PingAsync(foo); // where Ping takes IClient, not IFooClient
```

You can see more about configuring the server etc [here](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/gettingstarted).

What you *can't* do is:

```cs
channel.CreateGrpcService<IClient>();
```

This is because `IClient` here is a sub-service, which is purely a protobuf-net.Grpc concept meaning that `IClient` doesn't contribute to *routing*, but is instead flattened into any services that inherit it; at the HTTP level, this means that we're talking about `/foo/ping` vs `/bar/ping`, used to make sure we're talking to the right service. If we only know about `IClient` in isolation: we wouldn't know where to send it.

Comment: Actually i want to only know about IClient because specifically i don't want to handle `channel.CreateGrpcService<IBarClient>();`.
I will see this "code first" notation because it definitely has some advantages.
However as @JonSkeet and you mentioned, i can't do `channel.CreateGrpcService<IClient>();` so the solution for my specific problem would be to create a second dedicated service.

Comment: @LuftWaffle well, in that case mark `IClient` as `[Service]` rather than `[SubService]` - however, then `IClient` gets it's own routing and the interface inheritance seems ... pointless